# Scheme to avoid recomputation

Tags: python, performance, scala

**Motivation:**

For the sake of abstractness, I have a method treating a list of objects. Here I show a simplified version for illustration purpose (using Python2.7 here):

```
def foo(obj_lst, f):
    return list(map(f, obj_lst))
```

However, for some cases, the input could be `foo([obj] * 1000, f)`, then in the function call I have to recompute 1000 times of f(obj). We could possibly avoid it because all these are exactly the same object.

**My Solution:**

I can always cache the calculation result, as

```
def foo2(obj_lst, f):
    cache_map = {}
    def foo_single(obj):
        if id(obj) not in cache_map:
            cache_map[id(obj)] = f(obj)
        return cache_map[id(obj)]
    result_lst = []
    for obj in obj_lst:
        result_lst.append(foo_single(obj))
    return result_lst
```

And this does exactly the job I want and it can indeed speedup the recomputation overhead.

**My Question:**

This solution is not enough neat to me because I have to manually do so in every function, will there be a better solution for avoiding a general "same-object-recomputation" for non-random functions? A global cache_map with keys from function id and all arguments seems not work because the object ids are only unique during their lifetime.

In general I understand that this may not make too much sense in Python because these objects are mutable. May I ask if there is some existing scheme in functional programming languages like Scala dealing with this problem for immutable objects? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe some kind of function decorator?

Comment: Hi @ScottHunter, sorry I'm not quite familiar with that, can you give me some pointers?

Comment: Why do you "have to manually do it in every function"? You are passing the function as an argument, aren't you?

Comment: Oh @Dima, I was saying I have a lot of functions doing somewhat similar to  `foo`.

Answer (score 4):

You're describing [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

This can be done by [creating your own helper/decorator function](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_memoization.php) or using [functools.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) from the standard library (Python 3.2+)

Comment: Awesome! I'll try this out.

Comment: Right. It's memoization. An alternative I have done is to make the memory call-location-specific. In our particular usage, this made an enormous difference.

Comment: I just tried this but got some questions. Sometimes hashcode overhead may be too large when we have a large object and what we want is exactly whether or not it's the same object in memory pool. But using `id(obj)` may cause non-uniqueness problem outside `obj`'s lifetime. How can we properly define the decorator to make it really reflect it's really the same object we've seen? (Let's assume objects are always immutable though)

Comment: Apparently I misunderstood how decorator works! (Even worse maybe I misunderstood closure though...) Now I see that's exactly what I want! That's so awesome!!!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
 import java.util.{Collections, WeakHashMap}
 case class Memoized[T,R](f: T => R) extends Function1[T,R] {
    val mem = Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap[T,R])
    def apply(t: T) = Option(mem.get(t)).getOrElse { 
      val r = f(t)
      mem.put(t, r)
      r
    }
 }
```

You can then just do (among other uses) `foo(objectsWithDupes, Memoized(f))`

Comment: In some way, yeah ... There needs to be a way to tell if the two instances are "the same" or not. You can replace `t` with `id(t)` in `get` and `put` if you prefer.

Comment: Does Scala have its equivalent of python `id`? Sometimes objects itself are huge so compute hashcode itself is not enough reasonable...

Comment: I have no idea what python `id` is, but can't imagine what else can it possibly do if not returning a ref, and not computing a hashcode. I don't think there is any other way known to human-kind.

Comment: @ShenxiuLiu from python docs: "CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in memory.". So, `id(t)` in python is pretty much the same as just `t` in scala (somewhat worse actually, because scala overrides  hash and equality for many common kinds of objects). I think, "running into non-uniqueness problem" with it is a pretty looong shot. It's the last thing you need to worry about. More reason to be concerned here is having many different copies of the same object, with different memory addresses.

Comment: But we usually don't worry about different copies of the same object to much in functional programming languages because the objects are immutable so we always pass reference around. In my specific application it's also true that we only pass reference around and keep everything immutable though...

Comment: I don't know what it has to do with functional programming or mutability.
`"foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo"` are five different copies of the same, perfectly immutable, object.
If you are not worried about copies, then using the reference as memoization key is perfectly fine. Even if the hell freezes over, and an object is gc'd, and another one comes in with exactly the same address, it's not going to cause any problems, because, you won't find it in cache, and end up computing the result again, which is exactly what you want to do in the first place.

Comment: Hmm, avoiding copies is one of the major consideration of using immutable objects in functional programming. Specifically speaking your point, in Python, "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo" are five *same* objects with exactly the same address. I don't know how Scala do underlying but I wouldn't be surprised if they are treated in the same way. If objects are always immutable, it doesn't make sense to generate multiple copies for the same object.

Comment: Anyway it's not the topic here. May I ask why it's not going to cause any problems if the object is gc'd but we still use the address as key? Or I understand incorrectly?

Comment: First, let me repeat, and I cannot really stress this enough, that a collision like this  would be an event comparable by it's (im)probability to your laptop becoming self-aware and turning you into a slave in pursuit of world dominance. 

With that out of the way, to answer your question, what my implementation uses as a key, is not the address of the object itself, but a `WeakReference` to an object. If the object gets gc'd, the reference will, roughly speaking, turn into a null, so, the key will be effectively removed from the table.

Comment: Oh I see!!! Sorry I didn't know what WeakHashMap does and too ignorant that didn't check...... Now I do understand your point. Thanks and sorry for the confusion I made.